# HaProxy: use short timeout with balance source to distribute users more evenly?

Tags: haproxy

I've got a simple setup which consists of HaProxy running on one server which directs requests to two backend servers.

I'm stuck with using the source method of balancing for now as each request needs to go to the same server due to the application that's running on it.

However, in the past I've had a third backend server and some users are still being directed to that some days after I removed it from the config file and restarted HaProxy.

Also if I look in my HaProxy stats I can see that the bulk of users are being directed to one server and not the other - in other words it's not really load balancing just remembering which server uses were first connected to.

What I'd like to achieve is source balancing but perhaps with a short timeout so that a session will expire and then be reassigned to another server at a later date.  Is this possible ?  What changes do I need to make in order to spread the users more evenly and ensure that users are directed to servers that have been removed ?

I'm using HaProxy 1.5.8 and pretty much the default settings:

```
defaults
        log     global
        mode    http
        option  httplog
        option  dontlognull
        timeout connect 5000
        timeout client  50000
        timeout server  50000
        errorfile 400 /etc/haproxy/errors/400.http
        errorfile 403 /etc/haproxy/errors/403.http
        errorfile 408 /etc/haproxy/errors/408.http
        errorfile 500 /etc/haproxy/errors/500.http
        errorfile 502 /etc/haproxy/errors/502.http
        errorfile 503 /etc/haproxy/errors/503.http
        errorfile 504 /etc/haproxy/errors/504.http

frontend http_front
   bind *:2222
   stats uri /haproxy?stats
   default_backend http_back

backend http_back
   balance source
   server Private1 A.B.C.D:8080 check
   server Private2 E.F.G.H:8080 check
```

Comment: Using `balance source` isn't "remembering" anything.  [*"The source IP address is hashed and divided by the total weight of the running servers to designate which server will receive the request. This ensures that the same client IP address will always reach the same server as long as no server goes down or up. If the hash result changes due to the number of running servers changing, many clients will be directed to a different server. This algorithm is generally used in TCP mode where no cookie may be inserted."*](https://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/1.6/configuration.html#4-balance)

Comment: So what causes redirection to a third server no more live?